# How to validate numeric datatype length in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I have created a datagrid in asp.The grid is linked to this table that has few columns of numeric data type (22,8). I have these fields as editable ones and therefore I am trying to validate its precision and scale.
Currently I have this method which works for varchar data type:

```
var colList =
[
  ["customer_name", 32],
  ["customer_address", 32],
  ["price",22] // this is numeric (22,8)
];

for (var i = 0; i < colList.length; ++i) {
  if (currentColumnName == colList[i][0].toString()) {
    if (currentRowKey.toString().length > colList[i][1]) {
      var error = (colList[i][0].toString() + " can only have a maximum of " + colList[i][1] + " characters.");
      alert(error);
      eventArgs.set_cancel(true);

    }
  }
}
```

I want to validate numeric type with precision and scale. In code above I can validate length of 22 only I cannot validate only 8 digits allowed after decimal.Using regex can solve my issue and I am not good at it.

I tried to use the following :

```
var regex = [
        ["total_amount"],
        ["price"],
        ["market_value"]

              ];
              for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; ++i) {
                  if (currentColumnName == regex[i].toString()) {

                      var re = /^(\d{0,22}\.\d{0,8})$/;
                      if (regex[i].match(re)) {
                          var error = (regex[i]+"is incorrect");
                          alert(error);
                          eventArgs.set_cancel(true);

                      }
                  }
```

But it still does not validate

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Is the code throwing any errors?

Comment: It looks like you should use an object. `{customer_name:32, customer_address:32, price:22}`

Comment: I have it updated in the question. The code works fine to check length but I am trying to implement for numeric data type with scale and I want to be able to validate precision and scale eg. 23.56565656 - valid but 23.565656567 - should display error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to validate numeric data with precision and scale I used reg ex as my first method would handle length not numeric data validation.

The mistake in following code was 
1. I was trying to match column name and not data
2. "match" was not working for me so I used "test"

The code should be like

```
var currentRowKey = [eventArgs.get_displayText()];
var regex = [
        ["total_amount"],
        ["price"],
        ["market_value"]

              ];
              for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; ++i) {
                  if (currentColumnName == regex[i].toString()) {

                      var re = /^(\d{0,22}\.\d{0,8})$/;
                      if (!re.test(currentRowKey)){
                          var error = (regex[i]+"is incorrect");
                          alert(error);
                          eventArgs.set_cancel(true);

                      }
                  }
```

reg ex: The one in code works fine for those who want to handle decimal positive numbers only.

I wanted to handle whole numbers, +_ numbers, decimal numbers and nulls so I used the following:

```
var re = /^-?\d{0,22}(\.\d{0,8})?$/;
```